# How to know register ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2-select

How to know if the device in ionic 2 is registered or not in the code? I currently have this:

```js
private registerToken(){
    this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
        return this.push.saveToken(t,{
            ignore_user: true
        });
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
        console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the question? what's the result of your code? Do you have an error message?

Comment: Is not an error, it is a question of how you could know if the device is previously registered or not